# CDK deploy not recognizing my bootstrap and SSM parameter

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a project with CDK and CDK Deploy does not work. My project is a simple CDK app that has been started with `cdk init app --language typescript` and was working at first. I don't have anything but a lambda and an api gateway in this project.

After adding `NodejsFunction` from `@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs` I faced some errors but by installing docker locally and some changes all those were resolved and `synth` completes successfully now.

I run `cdk bootstrap` and then `cdk synth` and then `cdk deploy` with the last one here is the error I see: (the rest finishes successfully)

```
SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/pipeline/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
```

bootstrap and synth work fine, my `aws configure` has been done and no errors anywhere but the deploy doesn't work.

More details:
Error:

```
MyStackNameStack failed: Error: MyStackNameStack: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/pipeline/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.validateBootstrapStackVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:297:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.publishStackAssets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:272:7)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.deployStack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:179:5)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:184:24)
    at initCommandLine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:213:9)
MyStackNameStack: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/pipeline/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Package.json and CLI versions:

```
CDK version: 1.116.0

"@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway": "^1.116.0",
"@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.116.0",
"@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs": "^1.116.0",
"@aws-cdk/core": "^1.116.0",
```

Comment: Could you try deleting your [CDKToolkit stack](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home), running `cdk bootstrap` and `cdk deploy` again?

Comment: Make sure you have bootstrapped the environment (AWS Account + Region) you are trying to deploy to. It works easiest if you set a default region in "aws configure".

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue on my end by adding the `--toolkit-stack-name CDKToolKit` option to the bootstrap command

Comment: For me also this worked by adding this option, do not know why it is needed

Comment: @DKMDebugin I got error: 
 Environment aws://xxx/eu-west-1 failed bootstrapping: Error: The stack named CDKToolKit failed creation, it may need to be manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE

Answer (score 4):

I only use this:

```
cdk bootstrap
```

Comment: After running `cdk bootstrap` again I was able to run successfully `cdk deploy`